# Foreign keys in many-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys

I'm a bit confused about what needs to be stored in a many-to-many relationship table.

If I have two tables: Flight and Company what do I need to store in the table CompanyFlights?

For example, does this table only need to contain the flight's number and Company's unique name or does it also have to contain more information like the headquarters address of the company, flight's destination and departure location, etc.

And if the flight has two foreign keys for destination and departure locations ID's that reference another table Location?

Can the table CompanyFlights contain theses foreign keys that reference Location table that are foreign keys of the Flight table?

Comment: You can start from reading here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I think the only many-to-many relationship here is within this `flight` table you describe and that's between the departure and the destination location ids.

Comment: What Slava said.  Specifacally, 2nd normal form would preclude putting things like the Airline name in the junction table.  Some designers put extra attributes into the junction table.  But only if they depend on both foreign keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The minimum is two columns -- The Primary Key for each of the other two tables, perhaps you call them `flight_id` and `company_id`.  Each of those might be an `AUTO_INCREMENT` in their tables, but there is no need for an auto_inc in the mapping table.

See this for a discussion of indexing:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Everything specific to the flight should be in the `Flights` table.  Ditto for `Companies`.  It should *not* be in the many:many table.

A *few* schema designers add another column for ordering or some kind of qualification on the relation.